# Can't receive SMS message with Twilio trial account

Tags: express, sms, twilio-api

I have a small project (Express) using a Twilio trial account to send an SMS message to my phone number. But when I use my own message to replace the example string, I can't receive the SMS anymore.

This is what I tried:

- Verified my own number, so the Twilio phone number can send SMS messages to my own phone number.
- Verified the token and sid are the live credentials, not the testing one.
- Check the SMS Log, and the status of all messages are sent. But again, I don't receive anything.
- Used postman to verify the route if it is working properly. And yes, it did.

This is my code for the route to call the function to send the SMS

```
router.post("/contacts/sms", authorization, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { phone, message } = req.body;
    **sendSms(phone, message);**
    res.status(201).send({
      message:
        "Account created successfully, kindly check your phone to activate your account!",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
});
```

This is the SMS function

```
require("dotenv").config();

const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN; 

const sendSms = (phone, message) => {
  const client = require("twilio")(accountSid, authToken);
  client.messages
    .create({
      body: message,
      from: process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
      to: phone,
    })
    .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
};

module.exports = sendSms;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question, you might wanna have a look at that
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71912348/17503984

The problem might be since your Twilio phone number and the number you are sending are from different nationalities, communication problems arise due to the international SMS service