# Twilio SMS is sent but not Delivered

Tags: twilio, sms

Twilio SMS is sent but not Delivered
I'm using Twilio SMS service in my PHP application. Everything was going well but suddenly, I faced a problem that my SMS was sending but I'm not consistently receiving it on my phone--sometimes I receive SMS and sometimes I can't.

I've enough balance that is more than $200 in my Twilio account and my API key and AUTH key are perfectly ok. I've also checked the "from" number which is absolutely ok.

From the response after sending SMS, there are no errors and the delivery status is ok and it's reducing my balance as well.

Please someone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a programming problem, so I recommend you contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and provide them with example Message SIDs for messages that did not arrive.

Answer (score 1):

You can track sms status by including `StatusCallback` url to your request.

```
client.messages
      .create({
         body: 'McAvoy or Stewart? These timelines can get so confusing.',
         from: '+15017122661',
         statusCallback: 'http://postb.in/1234abcd',
         to: '+15558675310'
       })
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

You can find the document and sample code here - https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages#monitor-the-status-of-your-message

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with Twilio's API. The reason why you are not receiving the incoming SMS is maybe because you are sending the SMS to a mobile number that has a different country from your Twilio number.

For eg: If my Twilio number is from USA and I have to send an SMS to an Indian number, then the message is sent as an international incoming SMS, so it might face some communication issues and may not reach your number.

Twilio's support team has already provided an explanation for that, checkout here : https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133447-Not-Receiving-Incoming-SMS-and-MMS-Messages-on-Twilio-Phone-Number

[image]